# Can it be concluded that $z_ n \to z$ as $n \to \infty\ $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

Let $\{z_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of complex numbers and $z \in \mathbb C$ be such that for a given $\varepsilon \gt 0$ there exists $k \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n  \geq k$ we have $$|z_n - z| \lt \varepsilon \sqrt {1 + |z_n|^2}.$$

From here can it be concluded that $z_n \to z$ as $n \to \infty\ $?

Actually I have found this argument in the lecture note I am following but I am unable to figure that out. Any help in this regard would be warmly appreciated.

Thanks for investing your valuable time.

Comment: $|z_n|\leq |z|+\epsilon (1+|z_n|)$. Conclude that $z_n$ is bounded.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: What I have found is that for any given $0 \lt \varepsilon \lt 1,$ eventually we have $$|z_n - z| \leq \frac {\varepsilon (1 + |z|)} {1 - \varepsilon}.$$ So as $\varepsilon \to 0^+$ we are through. Is it fine?

Comment: That proves that $z_n \to z$: Show that given $\eta >0$ we can find $\epsilon >0$ such that $\frac {\epsilon (1+|z|)} {1-\epsilon} <\eta$.

Comment: "sending $\epsilon \to 0$" is not rigorous. Argue using $\epsilon - N$ definition instead...

Comment: If you add a bit more context (like where do you find this and how this is used, and what is your thought on that), I guess others will be more happy to post an answer.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: That's automatic because the function $x \longmapsto \frac {x} {1-x}$ is continuous at $x = 0$ and the functional value is zero at $x = 0.$ So we are done. Isn't it so?

Comment: @Arctic Char: The problem is solved by the hint given by Kavi Rama Murthy in his first comment. I don't think any further help is required. Thanks.

Comment: I mean, to post an answer. @AntonioClaire

Comment: @Arctic Char: As I have already mentioned in my question that I have found this in my complex analysis lecture notes in the context of the characterization of normal families in the spaces of meromorphic functions which can be thought of as continuous $\mathbb C_{\infty}$-valued functions defined on some region of the complex plane.

Comment: Your quantifiers are odd. Is $\varepsilon$ fixed?

Comment: @Will M.: Obviously not. **For a given $\varepsilon \gt 0$ there exists $k \in \mathbb N \cdots$**

Comment: Then don't say “for a given $\varepsilon” which sounds like the number is already fixed in advanced but “for every...”

Comment: @WillM. That's a weird nitpick. It is standard terminology in $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definitions of limit: "given $\epsilon\gt 0$, there exists $\delta\gt 0$ such that...", where $\epsilon$ is an _arbitrary_ positive constant (ie, the statement in ... considers $\epsilon$ fixed _after_ an arbitrary $\epsilon\gt 0$ is chosen).

Comment: I don't recall seeing "for a given" used in this context, @PrasunBiswas and if I saw "for a given $\epsilon>0$" and context were not given, I will assume that this $\epsilon >0$ is a fixed number. May be "for any given" would be clearer.

Comment: @ArcticChar: The question is talking about limits in the context of analysis: trying to conclude $z_n\to z$ from the statement $\forall\varepsilon\gt 0\exists k\in\Bbb N: |z_n-z|\lt\phi(z_n,\varepsilon)~\forall~n\ge k$; I'd say sufficient context is given to figure out what is the case here, though I agree with you on the point that "for (any) given $\varepsilon\gt 0$" would have been clearer. But, I've seen both usages (are common), and the former has one word ("any") less to write.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas I don't know where you learnt limits, but the standard $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of limit is that "for every $\varepsilon > 0,$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x - x_0| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon.$" _Often_, though, people omit quantifiers when they express something but the omission is like $f(x) = x^2-1$ for $x > 0$ (meaning actually _...for all $x > 0$_). So yeah, if you want to omit quantifiers, be careful, specially saying things like "for a given" when you mean "for every" (if you insist to use the former, write "for given...").

Comment: @WillM. I understand what you mean. We're just arguing semantics here, which is pointless. In the context of analysis, saying "given $\varepsilon\gt 0$, there exists $\delta$ such that..."/"for every $\varepsilon\gt 0$, there exists $\delta$ such that..."/"for a given $\varepsilon\gt 0$, there exists $\delta$ such that..." in informal language usually mean the same formal statement $\forall\varepsilon\gt 0\exists\delta\colon~...$, unless stated otherwise. I prefer the first one, but all three of them are commonly used.

Comment: @WillM. If the statement was supposed to hold for just _some_ $\varepsilon\gt 0$ and not all $\varepsilon\gt 0$, the informal sentence should be "For some $\varepsilon\gt 0$, ..." and **not** "for a given $\varepsilon\gt 0$, ...", or any variant thereof.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas I agree that "for every" and "for some" are far better and clearer than "for given" and "for a given" (whatever these last two are supposed to mean).

Comment: @Will M: Here what I mean by the phrase **given $\varepsilon \gt 0$ there exists $\delta \gt 0 \cdots$** is that **Give me an $\varepsilon \gt 0$ I will give you a $\delta \gt 0$ corresponding to that $\varepsilon \gt 0$ so that the inequality would hold.** Clearly that expresses $\delta$ as a function of $\varepsilon$ which is usually meant in the context of limits. I don't see how does it imply $\varepsilon$ is fixed.

Comment: @AntonioClaire I now know very well what you meant, but if you ever write something like that for a third party (say lecture notes), you are gonna give a very bad headache to a fraction of your audience since you are using the article "a" (which implies singular) when you mean that $\varepsilon$ is actually "another variable that will move eventually." In fact, on my first read, I thought you used $\varepsilon$ to mean a fixed radius and I thought, "is $\varepsilon$ fixed or moving"? Other people didn't thought that, but again, some definitely will since at least another agree with me.

Comment: @Will M: Yeah that article "a" ruined everything. Sorry for that. Pardon me please as english is not my mother-tongue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|z_n - z| \lt \varepsilon \sqrt {1+|z_n|^2}
\iff\frac{|z_n-z|}{\sqrt {1+|z_n|^2}}<\varepsilon,$$
this means
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|z_n-z|}{\sqrt {1+|z_n|^2}}=0.$$
We claim that:

> $\{z_n\}$ is bounded.

Otherwise, there exists subsequence $\{z_{n_k}\}$ such that
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}z_{n_k}=\infty,$$
but this implies
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{|z_{n_k}-z|}{\sqrt {1+|z_{n_k}|^2}}=1.$$
This is a contradiction.

Suppose $0\leq|z_n|\leq M$, then
$$0\leq\frac{|z_n-z|}{\sqrt {1+M^2}}\leq\frac{|z_n-z|}{\sqrt {1+|z_n|^2}}\to0,$$
which implies
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n=z.$$

Answer (score 0):

Kavi Rama Murthy's idea for proving the boundedness is a little bit easier.

First observe
$$\sqrt{1+|z_n|^2}\leq\sqrt{1+2|z_n|+|z_n|^2}=1+|z_n|$$
By triangle inequality, we have for all $n\geq k(\varepsilon)$
$$|z_n|\leq|z|+|z_n-z|\leq |z|+\varepsilon\sqrt{1+|z_n|^2}\leq |z|+\varepsilon(1+|z_n|) $$
By substracting $\varepsilon |z_n|$, we get
$$(1-\varepsilon)|z_n|\leq |z|+\varepsilon $$
Maybe, let $\varepsilon:=\frac 12$, then for all $n\geq k(\frac 12)$ holds
$$|z_n|\leq 2|z|+1. $$
The rest can be done, like Riemann already did.